# Maximo Anywhere Search WO

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

I am working on Maximo Anywhere 7.5.2 (WORK EXECUTION) app. I need to search WO based on my logged in user. As of now, It fetches complete work order.

Ex:
If user has be assigned to "ABC" and "ABD" WO, My search for "AB%" should return only these 2 records instead of fetching complete WO starts with "AB...." from Maximo.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch data for logged in user assigned WO either via adding whereclause in query or by filtering data in custom code after getting response from query.

I would suggest first approach since it fetches only required data.

Thanks